# BeautifulSoup4 tag content not showing

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I trying to scrape some data from a website and found a case where BeautifulSoup4 doesn't show whole content as I would expect it to. In the first example below everything works fine. After finding the tag with class "title" it shows it has two elements in content (NavigableText: Bag of Holding, and Span tag).

```
<h1 class="title">
    Bag of Holding
    <span style="float:right;">
        Item 4+
    </span>
</h1>
```

[image: Content of 'title' tag from first example]

Unfortunately in second case finding the title the same way it returns content with only 1 element, where I would expect there to be 3. I would expect content to contain the 'a' tag, text and the span, but it seems it only have the 'a' tag. It's making it really hard to get into the NavigableText as it's only accessible as 'next' element of the 'img'.

```
<h1 class="title">
    <a href="PFS.aspx">
        <span style="float:left;">
            <img alt="PFS Standard" title="PFS Standard" style="height:25px; padding:2px 10px 0px 2px" src="Images\Icons\PFS_Standard.png">
        </span>
    </a>
    Adventurer's Pack
    <span style="float:right;">
        Item 0
    </span>
</h1>
```

[image: Content of 'title' tag from second example]

Am I missing something obvious which would make getting the string from the title and following span consistent in both cases?

Edit:
I found that the issue is somewhere in parsing the html response, as it changes the one from 2nd example into something like:

```
<h1 class="title">
    <a href="PFS.aspx">
        <span style="float:left;">
            <img alt="PFS Standard" src="Images\Icons\PFS_Standard.png" style="height:25px; padding:2px 10px 0px 2px" title="PFS Standard"/>
        </span>
    </a>
</h1>
</span>
Adventurer's Pack
<span style="float:right;">
    Item 0
</span>
```

It seems to be caused by the html returned as even in raw html it looks like the `</a>` is appearing before `</span>` which makes me think that BeautifulSoup seeing something like this automatically closed the tag and upon finding next `</span>` it closed the header tag as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the issue was in the bad html response. The `<a>` tag was closed before the nested `<span>` tag which led to issues with default `html.parser`. I fixed it by using the `html5lib` parser with BeautifulSoup (`BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html5lib')`).